# How to call two functions simultaneously on click on a button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So there are 4 buttons in the component called Buttons. When they are pressed, they will be counter++, which means the number will be incremented by one. When the number changes, the color should also change. I couldn't do the color change. The increment is working.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Buttons from "./components/Buttons";
import Counter from "./components/Counter";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [counterColor, setcounterColor] = useState("");
  
  const changeCounter = (n) => {
    return setCounter(n + 1);
  };

  const arr = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
  
  const changeColor = () => {
    return setcounterColor(arr[0 + 1]);
  };
  
  console.log(counter);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter
        counter={counter}
        clazz={counterColor}
      />
      <Buttons
        changeCounter={() => changeCounter(counter)}
        changeColor={changeColor}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
function Buttons({ changeCounter, changeCounterColor }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(changeCounter, changeCounterColor)}>Click</button>{" "}
      <button onClick={changeCounter}>Click</button> <button onClick={changeCounter}>Click</button>{" "}
      <button onClick={changeCounter}>Click</button>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Buttons;
```

Comment: Two props to `changeCounter`? Can you please make it clearer?

Comment: 2 props should be sent to the parent component when the button is clicked. i.e. 2 props from button should come to app.js

Comment: Is it possible to send 2 functions to app.js at once via onClick.

Comment: In my code, I need the changeCounter and changeCounterColor props to be onClick simultaneously. Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: So when I click on the button it should be count+1 and the color of the number(count) should change.

Comment: I have updated my answer; take a look, and let me know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call `changeCounter` and `changeCounterColor` after one click on the button, you could do it like so:

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    changeCounter(1);
    changeCounterColor(1);
  }}
>
  Click
</button>
```

To have your color change with the counter, change `changeCouterColor` to:

```
const changeColor = (n) => {
  return setcounterColor(arr[n-1]);
};
```

Comment: Please also correct my code in app.js. The colors in the arr array should be changed to color via setColor in sequence.

Comment: I have to write the codes in one place, actually they are separate components. I still don't know how to use the site.

Comment: So there are 4 buttons in the component called Buttons. When they are pressed, they will be counter++, which means the number will be incremented by one. When the number changes, the color should also change. I couldn't do the color change. Increment is working.

Comment: It seems that I need to use methods such as map and forEach through the array.

Comment: I have updated my answer; take a look, and let me know please.

Comment: const changeColor = () => {
  return setcounterColor(arr[counter]);
};

Comment: Your code helped a lot. But arr[counter] is wrong. Because the counter must be infinite. And I have 4 colors.

Comment: I have 4 buttons. CounterColor should be red when button 1 is pressed, green when button 2 is pressed, 3-button blue, 4-button yellow.

Comment: When button 1 is pressed, arr[0] is red, when button 2 is pressed, arr[1] is green, etc. I don't know how to loop through an Array.

Comment: See my edited code. This would be for button 1; for the other, do the same thing, but increment the number.

Comment: You know, I struggled for 1 hour to write this code. You helped me a lot. Thank you very much. Greetings from Uzbekistan.

Comment: Glad I could Shuxrat! Greetings from France!